# How can I do a search for video on youtube in my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, youtube, gdata-api

In my iPhone application, I want to do a search for video on youtube.

How can I do this (with the GData API)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it the same as you would ask for any other data. If I wanted to search for youtube videos from my iPhone application, I would create a request to youtube that looked like this:

```
-(void)fetchYoutubeData:(NSString *)myQuery{
//where myQuery is the string to search for
//it needs to be encoded to stick in the url so Jimi%20Hendrix instead
///of Jimi Hendrix
NSError *err = [[[NSError alloc] init] autorelease];
NSString *myRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=%@&max-results=5",myQuery]; 
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myRequest];  
NSString *myYouTubeData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
if(err.code != 0) {
//HANDLE ERROR HERE
}
//Do Something with myYouTubeData here
}
```

You will need to parse the `myYouTubeData` string that you get back. The complete guide on how to structure your query can be found at the [YouTube API webpage](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters.html).

Comment: Hi, how to do the same search using gdata ?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. If you have a different question now, you should ask a new question. The code I gave you will work with any RESTful system by just changing the myRequest string.

Comment: how can do the search using gdata client in iPhone app ?

Comment: This API is deprecated now.