# Can I search youtube videos in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, search, video, youtube, categories

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I do a search for video on youtube in my iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067354/how-can-i-do-a-search-for-video-on-youtube-in-my-iphone-app)

I am writing an iPhone app that searches videos with category(tags) from youtube and playing them.
I can make it to play youtube videos in the app with url but I wonder how to search videos from youtube and get urls of videos in my iphone app.

Is there any sample code or tutorial to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067354/how-can-i-do-a-search-for-video-on-youtube-in-my-iphone-app

Comment: Thank you for quick help. Can you provide the GData API usage sample?

Answer (score 0):

sure look there how you can do this for begin in a webView:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://youtube.video.link.there";

    //Create a URL object.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

    //URL Requst Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [youtubeWebView loadRequest:requestObj];

    //This is for stop bounce of the webView if you want
    [[[youtubeWebView subviews] lastObject] setAlwaysBounceVertical:NO];

}
```

You can create a small browser web in youtube and load the result in a webView or if you prefer in a webView inside a different xib